# Create ASP.Net membership database structure in existing database

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I create all the ASP.Net tables, sprocs etc in a database that already has data (non conflicting) in it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have access to the database, run the following commands in command line:

```
cd "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"
aspnet_regsql
```

That will start a guide that will help you add all the tables and sprocs to any table you can access from that computer.

Answer (score 5):

From an article on [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203214/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx), go to the `%WINDOWS%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\` directory and run

`-- To use Windows Authentication (i.e., a "trusted connection"), use:`

`aspnet_regsql.exe -S <server> -E -d <database> -A all`

`-- To use SQL Server credentials (a UserID and Password), use:`

`aspnet_regsql.exe -S <server> -U <login id> -P <password> -d <database> -A all`

There is also a wizard to help you through the steps.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've been banging my head against the wall with the wizard, which appears to add the functionality but the permissions weren't correct. Command line is the way forward.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

http://blog.krisvandermast.com/CreateMembershipTablesInAnotherDatabaseThanTheStandardAspnetdbmdf.aspx

Comment: This does answer the question, but considering how easy it is it is better (for availability reasons) to actually write the answer than just posting the link. Won't vote you down though, as you did answer the question =)