# EF and ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a question about relating the Membership stuff in asp. How do I have a foreign key to the table (that asp creates) which has users that register on my website?
I am trying to use code-first for this and wonder how to create a POCO for this? what is the type of field I use? I assume it is off type GUID?
I am using VS2012 RC and so EF 4.5 (I think)

Comment: My $0.02: [Don't do this.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with creating actual Membership database on local server and explore it's structure via SQL Server Management Studio (or other utility if you're not using MS SQL Server). Instructions on how to do that can be found [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929646/625594) as well as in other answers to the same question.

Also [this blog post](http://superpatrick.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/aspnet-membership-schema/) features a [diagram](http://superpatrick.files.wordpress.com/2007/11/aspnet_membership_schema_updated.png) of EF relationships inside standard ASP.NET Membership database - unfortunately, it does not contain data types, but it shows approximate level of complexity of Membership tables and relations.