# managing and restricting roles without the use of membership

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application which requires two types of users, well 3 but the third one doesn't require a role: Admins which can access every page including the admin page which allows control over members; Members which can access every page except the admin page and they can post their data (high scores of a game); and guests which can visit all pages except the admin page and they can't do anything really.

Looking around I found out that ASP.NET has roles but they are tied to only three types of role providers(SqlRoleProvider, WindowsTokenRoleProvider, and AuthorizationStoreRoleProvider). Also I'm unsure but I assume that ASP.NET's Roles are connected to the whole Membership thing which means that unless I use the ASPNETDB.mdb database everything fails.

Anyway I have to restrict everyone but the admins from entrance to the admin page and allow members to post their scores. The idea I have now is that upon login, when I authenticate the user I store the user role into the cookiless session data and read it on every page load and proceed accordingly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net membership is not tied to a DB, you can roll your own, but I am assuming that you will be storing your users in a database of some sort, so the SqlProfileProvider is probably sufficent (this can be any database, does not need to be ASPNETDB.mdb).

Details on adding this support to existing DB is here: [Create ASP.Net membership database structure in existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929637/create-asp-net-membership-database-structure-in-existing-database)

You will need something like the membership, as you will need to login, you need roles, and this is what the membership API is all about.  It also uses industry standard storage etc., so that you don't code yourself a security hole by rolling it yourself.

You can then restrict either individual pages, or more commonly entire folders (e.g. an admin folder) by role using web.config files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't really matter how you call your database as long as you register the membership and roles services in your own database. It is as simple as running the `aspnet_regsql` command prompt tool without any parameters whatsoever and it will launch a wizard (.net style) to guide you through the installation of these services. ALL it does is create sql server objects in the database you wish (schemas, tables, sprocs, etc)
Now, if you dont like these built in providers (particularly I don't) there's nothing stopping you from implementing your own, it's quite simple but maybe a lengthy process due to the amount of abstract or virtual methods you'll need to implement/override depending on your approach or need. You two options to implement your own...

- one is implementing the`RoleProvider` abstract abstract class or
- extend/inherit from the `SqlRoleProvider` class which exposes a lot of virtual methods and properties.